# google sheets formula to extract time check in and checkout

Tags: date, time, split, timestamp, google-sheets-formula

Can someone help me with a formula to extract time from a specific checkin and checkout timestamp?

Here is an example of the time stamps:
Check-in = 2022-09-01T04:55:37
Check-out = 2022-09-01T08:00:44

In the check-in example, I would like to extract the 04:55 value and 08:00 in the check-out value.

I've tried =MOD, = Time,Minute, and Timevalue but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A2; "T");;2)
```

[image]

[image]